# DIfferences between 限定 and 制限

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I was trying to understand the differences between `限定` and `制限`, but I don't really get it: I found that [the former](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/906361) is generally a business term seen as positive and special, yet as example sentences I found `切符の数は限定されていた` (which isn't really positive) and `今話し合っている問題だけに発言を限定してく下さい`, which isn't necessarily business related.

[Here](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/1125622) they say `制限` is an upper/lower limit, while `限定` is to assign some amount, which I'm not sure is right/complete since again I found examples seemingly going against this, like `この版は７、０００部に限定されている` and `彼は会員数を２０に制限した`, which kinda seems similar, both imposing a man-made limit to something.

In [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12447/whats-the-difference-between-%E9%99%90%E7%95%8C-%E9%99%90%E3%82%8A-%E5%88%B6%E9%99%90-and-%E9%99%90%E5%BA%A6) there is some explanation, but it doesn't cover `限定`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think these are good examples to understand the difference between them easily.

このパーティーの参加者は、30歳に限定されている. It means "Only 30-year-old people can join this party".

このパーティーの参加者は、30歳に制限されている is unnatural because we can't know whether it means an upper limit or a lower limit. It must be "このパーティーの参加者は、30歳以上(以下)に制限されている. 限定 can be also used in this sentence as the same meaning.

Comment: So in `この版は７、０００部に限定されている` there is `限定` because they printed exactly 7000 copies, while in `彼は会員数を２０に制限した` there is `制限` because they accept up to 20 members (while it'd be fine also if they had less requests)? If so, is in `彼は会員数を２０に制限した` implied that 20 is an upper limit, and not like a lower limit to be able to get started? Given your reply I'd expect something like `彼は会員数を２０以下に制限した`.

Comment: 彼は会員数を２０以下に制限した is better, but I think 以下 can be omitted when it is obvious such as the number of attendance or the speed limit.